# Почему выводит сумму только 1-ой категории

Tags: php, html, html-form

```html
<form action="p2.php" method="POST">

<?php 
$sum = 0;
if($_POST['category']=="hunt")
{
 echo "Принадлежности для охоты<br>";
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h1'> Охотничье Ружьё - 9000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h2'> Капкан - 1500р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h3'> Охотничий лук - 3000р<br/>";
}
if($_POST['category']=="fish")
{
 echo "Принадлежности для рыбалки<br>";
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='f1'> Удочка - 1000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='f2'> Спиннинг - 3000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='f3'> Набор наживок - 350р<br/>";
}
if($_POST['category']=="games")
{
 echo "Принадлежности для компьютерных игр<br>";
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='g1'> Геймпад 2000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='g2'> Игровая клавиатура 3500р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='g3'> Игровая мышь 2500р<br/>";
}


echo "<input type='submit' name='sub' value='Выбрать'><br>";
              

?>
```

**И вот, на что ссылается.**

```html
    <?php
     
    $sum = 0; 
    if($_POST['h1']=="on")
    {       $sum+=9000;
    }
    if($_POST['h2']=="on")
    {       $sum+=1500;
    }
    if($_POST['h3']=="on")
    {       $sum+=3000;
    }
    if($_POST['f4']=="on")
    {       $sum+=1000;
    }
    if($_POST['f5']=="on")
    {       $sum+=3000;
    }
    if($_POST['f6']=="on")
    {       $sum+=350;
    }
    if($_POST['g7']=="on")
    {       $sum+=2000;
    }
    if($_POST['g8']=="on")
    {       $sum+=3500;
    }
    if($_POST['g9']=="on")
    {       $sum+=2500;
    }
    {
        echo "Общая стоимость снаряжения: ".$sum." рублей. <br/><br/>";
    }
    ?>
```

**На выходе я получаю сумму только первых трех принадлежностей, т.е. h1,h2,h3. Что я сделал не так?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему f4 f5 f6 g7 g8 g9? Параметры не совпадают, точнее, индексы массива post

Comment: А одним echo нельзя обойтись echo "<input><br><input><br>";

Comment: У вас в первом файле f1 f2 f3 g1 g2 g3. А во втором почему-то f4 f5 f6 g7 g8 g9

Comment: Упс. Что-то пошло не так. Всё, теперь всё работает. Через 5 минут ответ отмечу